# File Search (File Browse) through all Sub-Folders

Tags: file-browser

How can I Search Files through all Sub-Folders.

By default Blender only searches the root folder.

and I tried all given options, and couldn't see any icons that would allow me to search deeper.

I tried to find an addon that does that but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to search *all* sub-folders in the file browser, but you can search 3 levels deep by changing the *Recursion Level* drop-down box in the file browser header from *None* to *Three Levels*:

[image]

What this actually does is show  all the sub-folders in the file browser, which in turn allows them to be included in the search results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray, that solved it, 3 levels is good enough for me. Do you know if there is a way to safe it as default? I can't save it in the Start Up File, because as soon as you close the File Browse Window, it resets to None.

Comment: I have found it *does* remember which level of recursion it's set to. I went to *File> Open* set to level 3. Pressed *Cancel* then *File> Save Startup File*. New files now are by default set to level 3.

Comment: Great. it doesn't seem to work when using File > Open but it works when you use the CTRL ( CMD ) + O shortcut. Thanks Ray.